# Change image src doesn't work jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, gallery, src

I'm building my own photo gallery on my website, until now I've been using the full images as thumbnails too, but as you know that's not very efficient.

I'm trying to change the src of the image when clicking on the parent `<li>` but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code I've got:

```
$('.bild').click(function() {
                            $(this).toggleClass('bild').toggleClass('aktiv').addClass('bounceIn');
                            $('#letterboxFader').toggleClass('letterboxFader-active').toggleClass('letterboxFader-inactive');
                            $('.bild img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
                        });

                        $('.aktiv').click(function() {
                            $(this).toggleClass('aktiv').toggleClass('bild').removeClass('bounceIn');
                            $('#letterboxFader').toggleClass('letterboxFader-inactive').toggleClass('letterboxFader-active');
                            $('.bild img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('large','thumb'));
                        });
```

Note that I've only got the picture named "Coast Warning" set up with a thumbnail for test purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code expects that the `<li>` will have a "src" attribute, but it won't. To update the image source:

```
$(this).find("img").each(function() {
  this.src = this.src.replace("thumb", "large");
});
```

The "click" handler is on the `<li>` element, so the first thing you have to do is find the `<img>` that's in the clicked-on `<li>`.  The expression `$("img")` targets every `<img>` element on the page, which is not, I think, what you want to do. If you do, then the code should be:

```
$("img").each(function() {
  this.src = this.src.replace("thumb", "large");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I meant, I don't want this script to apply to all images.